# WCF - Missing integer parameter treated like 0

Tags: c#, wcf, web-services, soap, missing-data

I'm using WCF to generate a SOAP Webservice and right now I'm facing the following problem:

- I have an OperationContract defined that looks like this

`[OperationContract]
void InsertSomeData(string version, int someId);`

- While testing the service with soapUI I realized that if I delete the someId tags in the request I do receive the value 0 in my service
- Is this the standard behavior? Acutally I would suppose the service to throw some kind of Exception, as the parameter is not nullable.
- Can I differ in my service between 0 as real value that was passed and just missing tags, or do I have to make all of my parameters nullable in advance

Thank you for your help in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The hack-it-about way:

```
[OperationContract]
public void InsertSomeData(MyData data){...}

[DataContract]
public class MyData{
[DataMember]
public string version{get;set;}
[DataMember(IsRequired=true)]
public int someId{get;set;}

}
```

A longer winded, but better way: http://thorarin.net/blog/post/2010/08/08/Controlling-WSDL-minOccurs-with-WCF.aspx

Comment: Unfortunatelly approach no.1 is no option for me. The interface is pre-defined although I know that it would be a much better (and extensible/adaptable) idea to use a "Request-Object" than passing multiple parameters. I have to check on approach no.2 as it is more complex

Comment: if you find a better way, let me know please! :)

Comment: I think No.2 is pretty sure a really good solution, although it seems to be rather complex for solving a basic task. As I stated in my question I was a little bit shocked by this behaviour as I wasn't expecting it. I'm new to WCF and thought that Microsoft will deal with this requirement in a more comfortable way...

Comment: Finally, although approach No.2 is rather complex it's working for me well. Accepted :)